# How to use -source from Tcl in python?

Tags: python, tcl, opensees

I am doing an analysis in Opensees, which can be written in tcl or Python (Openseespy).

In tcl the following line of code can be written:

```
eleLoad -ele $eleID -type -beamThermal -source BeamTemp.txt
```

In python the equivalent would be:

```py
op.eleLoad('-ele', beamTag, '-type', '-beamThermal', ....)
```

where the dots indice some way of getting the temperature data from the text file.

I am not sure what the python equivalent would be to reading variables from a text file in the same way tcl would?

Comment: Is `-source` really a Tcl feature or just a feature of OpenSees?

Comment: It sounds to me like a feature of OpenSees. The obvious thing to try is passing the values (option name, filename) as strings; that's probably what the implementation expects.